# Cloth Animation

Tags: animation

First off i am fairly new to blender and am trying to create a opening Sequence of a hand pistol been cocked and fired and a flag dropping from a cylinder like the old joke pistols with the bang flag at the moment i am just running small scale trials using two cylinders and a small plane as the cloth but the plane which is parented to the smaller cylinder passes thought the larger cylinder

[image]

Answer (score 1):

you need to select the big cylinder, go to Physics > Enable Collision > Enable Rigid Body and then on Rigid Body Type select Passive. Look the image.

[image]

And this is the result.

[image]

Cloth settings

[image]

Comment: thank you Francisco you have been a great help,
Are thoses the default cloth settings